# How to add words to sphinx?

Tags: sphinx4

How to add my words to sphinx using java?
Iam a new learner for learning sphinx,I just know how to use it.I want to learn adding my words.anybody can help me.

Answer (score 3):

Add the word to the dictionary file sphinx4/models/acoustic/wsj/dict/cmudict.0.6d:

> ABACK                AH B AE K
>
> ABACO                AE B AH K OW
>
> ABACUS               AE B AH K AH S
>
> **PINTREST             P IH N T R EH S T**

Then add the word to the grammar sphinx4/src/apps/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/helloworld/hello.gram:

> #JSGF V1.0;
>
> grammar hello;
>
> public  = (Good morning | Hello) ( Bhiksha | Evandro | Paul | 
>       Philip | Rita | Will | **Pintrest** );

Recompile and run HelloWorld demo, it will understand a new word.

If the word is already in the dictionary, you can just add it to the grammar.

Comment: According to http://www.coderanch.com/t/62853/open-source/Sphinx-custom-dictionary, you can also use edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.FastDictionary to avoing having to recompile Sphinx from source each time.